# Iterate through list passed as **kwargs in cheerypy python

Tags: python, cherrypy

Hi I am new to cheerypy and python

I am passing list of objects

EX:

```
deviceArr=[{"id":"01","name":"abc"},{"id":"02","name":"abcd"}]
```

to the Post request

```
      def POST(self,*args, **kwargs):
            abc=[]
            abc=kwargs['deviceArr']
            print abc #output -[{"id":"01","name":"abc"},{"id":"02","name":"abcd"}]
            for device in abc:
                print device #its printing [,{,",i,d...
```

i want it to print complete object on Iteration

```
    {"id":"01","name":"abc"}
    {"id":"02","name":"abcd"}
```

so can any one please help me how to achieve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post data is being received as a JSON object which is a string. You need to convert it to a Python object first, in order to iterate over your data as a list of dictionaries and not as a string:

```
import json

...
abc = kwargs['deviceArr']
abc = json.loads(abc)
...
```

Comment: getting error
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `abc` is a string. Turn it to an actual Python dict with the `json` module:

```
import json

.
.
.

abc = json.loads(kwargs['deviceArr'])
```

Comment: getting error
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Comment: lol, that dots do represent your code. you were not supposed to copy-paste them